# jQuery - как добавить атрибут onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня ситуация, когда мне нужно добавить переменные к функции по событию OnClick, которые предварительно выводятся php скриптом на каждый объект, они разные на каждом из объектов: `onclick="моя функция('переменная 1', 'переменная 2');`, т.е. таких `onclick` на одной странице может быть множество, а переменные жестко вписаны в HTML и выводятся посредством перебора `for` массива объектов в php. Функция одна для всех объектов.

Так же у каждого из объектов назначен класс `class="note<?php echo $row->id; ?>"`, где к классу добавляется `id` объекта по номеру в БД, чтобы знать с каким из них далее работать в моей функции `js`.

В функции js происходит смена `переменной 2`, `переменная 1` же всегда остаётся неизменной, это тот же номер (ID) объекта, что добавляется к классу, берётся из БД, опять таки нужен для того, чтобы знать, с каким из объектов работать.

Полностью функцию показывать не имеет смысла, так как собственно она прекрасно работает, но после завершения её, я хочу заново повесить атрибут `onclick` на объект с новым значением `переменной 2`, чтобы можно было снова вызвать функцию, в чём и загвоздка.

Здесь, сразу после вызова функции, я обнуляю событие по клику, чтобы можно было далее с объектом работать и событие не возникало постоянно заново, пока не знаю как по другому это можно сделать:

```
jQuery('.note' + id).attr('onclick', '');
```

далее, после отработки Ajax функции, я пытаюсь заново повесить атрибут `onclick` на объект с новым значением `переменной 2`, но я уже понял, что это не будет работать:

```
jQuery('.note' + id).attr('onclick', 'noteAgent(\'' + id + '\', \'' + newnote + '\');');
// по русски:
моя функция('переменная 1', 'новая переменная 2');
```

Интересует, почему не работает добавление атрибута `onclick` в jQuery, и способ, как это можно реализовать "по другому", может быть используя делегирование событий, но при делегировании я пока представления не имею как передать эти переменные в обрабочик события, да и "слушать" всю таблицу на предмет клика, когда объект в ней относительно мал, не хочется.

Comment: @Igor обнуление работает, но значение onclick не меняется, как и прежде, почему-то

Comment: @Igor я вроде бы по русски выражаюсь, не понимаю, к чему вы всё время придираетесь: у каждого атрибута есть значения (href="значение", onclick="значение", src="значение" .......) или это нужно вам разжевывать ссылками на htmlbook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Обнуление события по клику" не стоит делать с помощью `.attr('onclick', '')` или `.removeAttr('onclick')` хотя бы потому-что такой код не будет работать в IE < 9. Вместо этого нужно искользовать `.prop('onclick', null);` (см [документацию `removeAttr`](http://api.jquery.com/removeattr/#entry-longdesc)).

Поэтому я поддерживаю **newman** и настоятельно рекомендовал бы Вам использовать `.click(function (e) {...})` или, что то же самое, `.bind("click", function (e) {...});` вместо `.attr('onclick', ... )`. Для удаления хэндла можно использовать `.unbind("click")`.

Использование `.click` или `.bind("click",...)` существенно упрощает программирование. Я упомяну лишь два важных факта:

- `onclick` атрибут **один** на элемент, а с помощъю `.click` или `.bind("click",...)` можно зарегистрировать *несколько* хэндлов. Использование `.unbind("click")` с дополнительными параметрами позволяет удалить *отдельный* хэндл без побочных эффектов.
- хэндл, зарегистрированный с помощью `onclick` атрибута, выполняется в *глобальном* контексте, в то время как хэндл, зарегистрированный с помощью `.click` или `.bind("click",...)` может испольновать любые переменные из внешнего контекста. Это существенно упрощает использование параметров. К тому же `jQuery` поддерживает много дополнительных видов использования. Я не хочу дублировать документацию `jQuery` и приведу лишь один пример использования `.bind("click", eventData, handler)`

```html
<button id="b1" class="note">Button 1</button>
<button id="b2" class="note">Button 2</button>
```

```js
var localVar = 0, myCompexObj = { test: "a" };

$(".note").bind("click", {x: 2, obj: myCompexObj }, function (e) {
    var myCoxtext = e.data;
    console.log("e.target.id=" + e.target.id);
    console.log("localVar=" + localVar);
    console.log("myCoxtext:");
    console.log(myCoxtext);

    localVar++;
    myCoxtext.obj.test = "b" + localVar;
    myCoxtext.newProp = "x" + localVar;
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/jqcvczf9/1/. Для простоты я вывожу все на консоль. Поэтому, нужно открыть консоль, чтобы видеть результаты работы. Результат после нажатия первой, второй и опять первой кнопки выглядит так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возможно, покажется, что я слегка перемудрил с параметрами, но я, просто, хотел ясно показать, что **можно реализовать много разных сценариев** таким путем, причем очень просто.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется вы немного не так используете jQuery. Это как микроскопом орехи колоть.

Для начала, не нужно задавать параметры в виде аргументов функции в HTML. Можно "хранить" эти данные прямо в аттрибутах тега. Например так:

```
<a href="#" data-param="1" id="1" class="note">click 1</a><br />
<a href="#" data-param="2" id="2" class="note">click 2</a>
```

Обработчик onclick на все данные можно поставить через класс *note*. А обращаться к аттрибутам тега можно не через селектор, а через конструкцию `$(this)` внутри обработчика. Тогда код на JS будет, например, таким

```
$('.note').click(function(){
  var str = "ID:" + $(this).attr('id');
  var val = $(this).attr('data-param');
  str = str + " PARAM: " + val;
  val++;
  $(this).attr('data-param', val);
  alert(str);
});
```

В данном коде устанавливается обработчик *onclick* для всех элементов с классом *note*. В коде получаем значение **id** элемента, а так же значение аттрибута **data-param**. Знчение этого аттрибута изменяется - так что при следующем клике функция будет работать уже с другими значениями.

Думаю я правильно понял основной смысл вашей задачи.

Живой пример можно посмотреть на [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/0r1q7sg1/)

Comment: да, я уже начал реализовывать подобным способом, но меня всё равно дико интересует, почему onclick никак нельзя поменять) спасибо за ответ!

Comment: @Blacknife все работает: https://jsfiddle.net/8bLLbqz6/ Попробуйте использовать не `class` а `id` для идентификации элемента. В вашем случае это более логично.